# How to create sprite of about 200 images?

Tags: jquery, seo, css-sprites

I have a website, where I am in need to load about 200 images of same size 150*150.

I can't create different sprites having 20-30 images in one. As the image path are coming from database. It is appended using jQuery as below.

```
<ul id="albumsIcons">
</ul>

$('#btnGetAlbums').on('click',function(e)
{
   $.ajax(
   {
       url : "Controller/Action",
       type : "GET",
       success : function(data)
       {
            $.each(data,function(album)
            {
                $('#albumIcons').append('<li id='+album.Id+'>
                                          <img src='+album.imgPath+'/>album.Name </li>
            }
       }
   }
}
```

I have to load min 100 albums in one call.

So I thought of creating sprite, I have checked almost 5-6 links but they all take 20 images max for a sprite.

- http://spritepad.wearekiss.com/
- http://instantsprite.com/
- http://www.piskelapp.com/

Any link that can create meet my requirement. or any alternate solution for my requirement.

Comment: You can create a normal PNG image with any software, but then you just have to discover the coordinates to each image with background-position..

Comment: But using huge sprites is a compromise, as you can read here..
https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/03/css-sprites-useful-technique-or-potential-nuisance/

Comment: @miguelmpn but that will be too tedious to identify the x,y co-ordinates of the 200 images, but if you any link to create such png, please post, I will check & see

Comment: @miguelmpn.. the what could be better soultion for such scenario

Comment: yes that was my thought on the first comment, here is an example link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZyFtli8HK9A

Answer (score 1):

I would do that with [SmartSprites](http://csssprites.org/): its default purpose is to transform CSS files with single sprites (meaning: one single image file per sprite) into CSS files with only one image file (or actually as many as you like) for multiple sprites.

SmartSprites will turn something like this...:

```
/** sprite: mySprite; sprite-image: url('/mySprite.png'); sprite-layout: horizontal */

#albumIcons li
{
    width:150px;
    height:150px
}
#img1
{
    background-image:url(/images/1.png); /** sprite-ref: mySprite; */
}
#img2
{
    background-image:url(/images/2.png); /** sprite-ref: mySprite; */
}
```

... into this:

```
#albumIcons li
{
    width:150px;
    height:150px
}
#img1
{
    background-image: url('/mySprite.png');
    background-position: -0px top;
}
#img2
{
    background-image: url('/mySprite.png');
    background-position: -150px top;
}
```

But the main result is your new image file that is to be found (and re-used) in /mySprite.png.

Multiple mentions of the first line (the smart sprite definition) are possible, thus enabling you to generate more than one output file.